# Bootstrap menu close automatically when expanded

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I wrote a media query that remove the hamburger menu automatically on a certain resolution but for some reason, when the menu is collapsed and I try to expand it, the menu is closing automatically, this is the code:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggler {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-left,
  .navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggler {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    float: none !important;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .collapse.in {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50?text=Logo" alt="">
        </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

as you can see this happen only when the menu is collapsed and I try to expand it, what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the property:

```css
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  /* ... */
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

After the animation, Bootstrap adds a collapse class to your menu.
You're overwriting the default behavior hiding the menu for every resolution less than 1200px.

I hope this answer could help you!

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggler {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-left,
  .navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggler {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    float: none !important;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .collapse.in {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50?text=Logo" alt="">
        </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I see the problem and I've applied your fix, but this has generated another problem: I would like to collapse the menu items automatically when a resolution less than of 1200 is reached, your solution doesn't hide this item but just show the hamburger menu item. Is there any way to bring back the old logic removing the old issue?

Comment: Oh, maybe you need something like:

`@media (min-width: 1200px) { .navbar-collapse.collapse {display: none !important;}}`